# Name Attribute "Styling"?

Tags: html, css

I have a really weird question.

I have name attributes in my html, and when I test the links to the name, the text is immediately at the top of the screen, like so (behind the fixed div at top)

Before I click the link: http://pbrd.co/1kzcF6U

After: http://pbrd.co/1kzcBUW

I don't want it to do that. How would I 'style' the [name] to view supposedly 100px below where it automatically shows when I [name]d it?
For example, instead of the first "after" (linked above), How I would I get it to view like this: http://pbrd.co/1kzd5uf when I click it?

I'm sorry if this is confusing.

My codes (I'm not sure it's needed?):

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #846D8C;
}
a[name] {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#333333;
}
```

EDIT: I want to use NO Javascript or jQuery, please tell me EXACTLY what to do with this. Please do not just link me to another; that doesn't clarify anything.

Comment: I believe this isn't a duplicate, because I do not understand what he/she was asking at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind I figured it out on my own, thanks for the help (sarcasm).

I simply added a

```
padding-top: ##px;
margin-top: -##px;
```

to the

```
a[name] {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#333333;
    margin-top:-100px;
    padding-top:100px;
}
```

and it works without a problem.